# Why is jQuery.extend() faster than Lodash .clone()

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

For a very large JSON object with up to for nested levels, jQuery.extend() seems to be significantly faster than the lodash clone method when deep cloning the object. How are these two methods different from each other, and what leads to the discrepancy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jQuery.extend` does not deep clone.  It simply copies properties from the source objects into the target object.  If the properties are object references, they get copied too.  This is known as a shallow copy.

It may look like a deep copy if you inspect each object, but the properties are references to the same underlying objects.

The `deep` option for `jQuery.extend` results in a merge, not a copy, meaning that objects will not be over-ridden, but have their properties copied onto.

For details, see the documentation for `jQuery.extend`:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Comment: Thank you Brandon. What happens to the references, when removing entries from the original array? It seems that one can still access the data through the clone. Is it a matter of time until the garbage collector removes the data, or will they live on?

Comment: The garbage collector may be delayed in  removing the data, but it would only be able to delete it if the references are gone, at which point the data is invisible.  Copying an object reference and removing it from somewhere else doesn't delete the object.  You now have another reference to the same object.